# ASP.NET MVC: How to reliably get the real URL of the current request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Right now I have an MVC application running on http://127.0.0.1:8081/ (it is actually running in the Azure compute emulator). The browser location bar clearly says 8081 for the port number.

However, `Request.Url` and `Request.RawUrl` both give me http://127.0.0.1:8082/.

I need to send an e-mail with a URL in it, so I need the correct hostname and port number. How do I get the actual, real URL reliably and without such unexpected deviation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768232/request-url-port-giving-wrong-port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Request.Headers["Host"];` which will give you the host name (or IP) with the correct port number. Then you can reconstruct the URL.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the hostname and portnumber — but now that I know what the underlying problem is, I am worried that the same problem will happen with the Scheme (a.k.a. protocol), which is *not* part of the Host header... :(

Comment: As long as there is a load balancer/router (Azure) between the request and the service, this sort of port/IP changes are always possible at any level. I can't imagine one global solution to be honest.

Comment: (The *correct* solution, obviously, would be to fix the bug in ASP.NET that sets the wrong port number in the first place. But due to overly-religious backwards compatibility, that will never happen...)

Answer (score 3):

you can also use:

```
Request.Url.Host
```

or use (if you want all the initials and not just the host):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
string Domain = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host +       (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port);
return View(Domain);
}
```

this was taken from 'Abundant Code'
[How to Retrieve the Current Domain in ASP.NET MVC?](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-retrieve-the-current-domain-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

In the cloud as Azure, your process may run anywhere with any port number. the current request will get routed to the process.

that's why you will always have different port number.

It is better that you specify your domain name in the web.config file; it will always be the same for all the request if you read from the config file.