# C# - QR code link in case of load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, uri, load-balancing, qr-code

I am completely new in this part - I have a QR code on my screen which works for both windows and mobile i.e. you can click on that QR code to open a new window with given page in same browser on window or you can scan the QR code which will open that page in your mobile phone.

previously we have single server it was working fine. We were generating the URL for that QR code as follows -

```
 var urlBuilder = new System.UriBuilder(HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
 {
      Path = Url.Action(actionName, controllerName),

      Query = "ID=" + model.abc
  };

  return urlBuilder.ToString();
```

This used to return the url as "http://site.internal/Controller/Action"

This was working for both desktop & mobile

Now we have deployed app on multiple servers and got the load balancer.

Now URL of the application has changes  -

E.G. Load Balanced External URL = https://secure.abc.com

Now when we generate an URL for QR code using same code then it takes the server URL i.e it points to server URL (http://site.internal/Controller/Action) instead of Relative path/current URL.

Is there a way to solve this issue? to take relative path instead of server path?

---

**Edit -** I tried changing the code as

```
 var urlBuilder = new System.UriBuilder(HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
 {
      Path = Url.Action(actionName, controllerName),

      Query = "ID=" + model.abc
  };

 var cleanUrl = urlBuilder.Uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Scheme & ~UriComponents.Host & ~UriComponents.Port,
                           UriFormat.UriEscaped);

  return cleanUrl.ToString();
```

But it works only on Desktop. It does not work on mobile phone as there no URL present on phone when we scan the QR code

Comment: Do you dynamically create the QR using that same url? Or is it a fix image? If the latter, then you need to change to the former.

Comment: I am dynamically creating a QR code

Comment: Can you confirm that QR creation methods use the correct uri?

Comment: yes its using the correct uri

Comment: I assume the load balancer isn't passing through the URL being requested by the browser? Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889827/asp-net-mvc-how-to-reliably-get-the-real-url-of-the-current-request)?

Comment: You could add the external url in appsettings from web.config and replace HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri with Configuration.AppSettings["ExternalUrl"]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, only way i found is to keep the external url key in web.config and replacing the absolute uri with external url key.

Other way is by assigning that value to environment variable on server